# Separate output of multiple JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm trying to separate a couple of objects by filtering the keys. For example I may want to output the data of  the "yar" and "foo" objects in the first table and the rest in the second table.

This results in **ONE** complete table:

```
console.log(data);
var firstTable = 'yar foo'.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        html = '<tr data-item="' + key + '"></tr>';
    }
    $('table#one tbody').append(html);
}
```

The result I'm after:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr data-item="yar"></tr>
  <tr data-item="foo"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr data-item="bar"></tr>
  <tr data-item="rawr"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

console.log(data) returns:

```
0: Object
    foo: Object
        lorem: Array[2]
            0: "1"
            1: "2"
1: Object
    bar: Object
        lorem: Array[2]
            0: "1"
            1: "2"
2: Object
    yar: Object
        lorem: Array[2]
            0: "1"
            1: "2"
3: Object
    rawr: Object
        lorem: Array[2]
            0: "1"
            1: "2"
```

I've tried to match `key` with `$.inArray(key, firstTable)` but the first for-loop makes me end up with too many rows. Glad for any help I can get!

Comment: Your data is very wired structured for your request. What will be the criterion with real data? Only every 2nd row or special keys in the data?

Comment: @DrColossos the first table should match the keys defined in `firstTable` and the second table should output all the others.

Comment: A working jsfiddle would help

Comment: so your "the result I am after" is in actuality `<table id="one">` in the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the rows to their respective tables one-at-a-time, and remember that inArray doesn't return true or false - it returns the index (0..n) of the item in the array, or -1 if the item isn't there.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        html = '<tr data-item="' + key + '"></tr>';

        if ($.inArray(key, firstTable) >= 0)
          $('table#one tbody').append(html);
        else
          $('table#two tbody').append(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was thinking outside of the box when the answer was in it... Works like a charm, thanks a bunch @Paul Roub!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but try adding a break in the loop.

```
var firstTable = 'yar foo'.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        html = '<tr data-item="' + key + '"></tr>';
    }
    break;
```

Then you would output the rest of the table.

```
for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        html = '<tr data-item="' + key + '"></tr>';
    }
// ...
```